# Is the unbiased test always uniformly most powerful?

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing

I know that the uniformly most powerful test is always unbiased, if it exists, but is the unbiased test always UMP?

Comment: You've asked a reasonable mathematical question, but you provided little in the way of context.  This is a natural omission for new users, because the context is of course well-known to yourself.  But explaining what motivates the problem or how you researched it before posting can add significantly to the benefit of Readers present and future. Please edit the body of your Question.

Answer (score 3):

No. Consider a randomized test that rejects the null with probability $\alpha$, independent of the data. Then the test has equal type 1 error and power and is unbiased level $\alpha$, but not necessarily UMP.